# The char* member of a struct gets overwritten by strcmp?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, struct, char

i've got an own implemented list:

```
struct NodeComposition {
    Int32 index;
    Int8 address;
    char* label;
    NodeComposition* next;
};
```

and I am creating new structs with the following method, whereas the label of the root element is initialized with NULL and is changed later on.

```
NodeComposition ListManager::getNewNode(char* label, Int8 address)
{
    NodeComposition* newNode = new NodeComposition;
    newNode->address = address;
    newNode->label = label;
    newNode->next = 0;
    newNode->index = -1;
    return *newNode;
}
```

In order to check if a specific "label" exists I have implemented following method:

```
NodeComposition* ListManager::labelExists(char* label)
{
UInt32 i = 0;
NodeComposition* conductor = &rootNode;

// Traverse through list
while(i < elements)
{
    // Label has been found

    if (strcmp(conductor->label, label) == 0)
    {
        return conductor;
    }

    /* Advancing in list */
    else
    {
        if(conductor->next != 0)
        {
            conductor = conductor->next;
        }

        else
        {
            /* Error: Null reference found in conductor->next */
            return NULL;
            //return Errors::NULL_REFERENCE;
        }
    }

    i++;
}
/* label not found */
return NULL;
}
```

And here comes my problem:

- I called the `labelExists(char* label)` method (With a linked list of two elements)
- After it compares the two strings it changes the value of the member `label` of the **second element** inside of the first iteration

This data is some random trash out of my main memory and I do not have any idea why it behaves like that. Additionally, exactly this code worked just an hour before. At least I think that it did because I can not remember changing any code.

Does anybody has an idea?

Thank you!

Edit:
here is some additional code

```
NodeComposition newNode = getNewNode(label, address);
ListManager::addNode(newNode);


Int32 ListManager::addNode(NodeComposition node)
{
node.index = elements;
lastNode->next = &node;
lastNode = &node;
elements++;
return lastNode->index;
 }
```

Comment: If you're working in C++, then strongly prefer `std::string` to all this raw `char *`, `strcmp` stuff.

Comment: I am working in C++ but I am not allowed to use std::string :(

Comment: I'd like to see the function that calls getNewNode.

Comment: Since `strcmp` is not a function that "writes", it is clearly not "strcmp" that causes the problem (unless seriously bad implementation). What is the code that actually stores `label`?

Comment: MatsPetersson: I do know that it - well - should not write anything. But this happens exactly after that comparison. Actually this is the step where it happens inside of the eclipse debugger ..
@EricFinn I'll add that code in a couple of seconds

Comment: So following on from the code you've just added: Where does `label` come from in this line `NodeComposition newNode = getNewNode(label, address);`

Comment: Can you construct a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/#selfcon) (as in post a complete program that we can copy and paste into an IDE on our own computers, or [an online compiler](https://ideone.com)) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what happens is something like "... char label[X]; ... getNewNode(label, address);`  - where label is always pointing to the same local variable.

Comment: Your code has a memory-leak: You are creating a local instance of the struct with a pointer and `operator new` (Why? Why you don't use a local variable?), and you are returning the dereferenced value of the pointer by value, so the original data is leaked. AVOID THE USE OF POINTERS IN C++!!! And don't do really freaking things like dereferencing a pointer and return the result by value!

Comment: Since you merely copy the pointer into the label member in `getNewNode()`, rather than making a new allocation and copying into that, it seems likely to me that you're not properly duplicating the label before you call `getNewNode()`.  You might also be passing a pointer to automatic storage which is being reused by `strcmp()` and appears to clobber your structure, but the real problem is that your structure member is pointing to improper memory.

Comment: @MatsPetersson `void DsFlowControl::addJumpLabel(char* label)
{
 listmanager->addLabel(label, m_CmdCount);
}`
and I am calling that method like: `obj->addJumpLabel((char*)"LABEL")`

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely not strmcp, so let's not focus on that. You should clean up this code first.  There are memory leak and corruption going on.

To start with:

```
NodeComposition ListManager::getNewNode(char* label, Int8 address)
{
    NodeComposition* newNode = new NodeComposition; // $#!^!memory allocated
    newNode->address = address;
    newNode->label = label;  // $#!^! is label allocated on stack or heap? possible leak & corruption
    newNode->next = 0;
    newNode->index = -1;
    return *newNode; // $#!^!return by value. newNode is now lost! memory leak
}
```

Then in your additional code:

```
NodeComposition newNode = getNewNode(label, address); // $#!^! getting a copy of the "newNode" only. This copy is allocated in stack.   
ListManager::addNode(newNode); //$#!^! adding a stack object onto linked list


Int32 ListManager::addNode(NodeComposition node)
{
    node.index = elements;
    lastNode->next = &node;
    lastNode = &node;  //node is actually allocated from stack, not heap! likely memory corruption here!
    elements++;
    return lastNode->index;
 }
```

Comment: Actually this is not the only way I tried to implement the getNewNode method. Initially I created a newNode on the stack like `NodeComposition newNode; newNode->address ...`. but I thought that I'd had some buffer overflow issues. 

However, the debugger shows the correct values before the `strcmp`. But I guess you're right - it has to be a memory leak. I'll try it again tommorow. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer .. I modified my code like this:

```
Int32 ListManager::addNode(NodeComposition* node)
{
node->index = ++elements;
lastNode->next = node;
lastNode = node;
return lastNode->index;
}

NodeComposition* ListManager::getNewNode(char* label, Int8 address)
{
NodeComposition* newNode = new NodeComposition;
newNode->address = address;
newNode->label = label;
newNode->next = 0;
newNode->index = -1;
return newNode;
}

NodeComposition* ListManager::labelExists(char* label)
```

The use of pointers helped me out - Thank you guys.